# Manipulate folder names with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to be able to "edit" the folder name of a file with a batch script. For example if the folder is 20011993 I would like to be able to add or delete characters in any position by setting a variable. A few output examples would be:

> 20_01_1993, 2-1-1993, 20-01-1993, 1993.

I realize that i should theoretically be able to do this using delims and tokens but I need a little help.

---

1.

This code will remove the 6 characters of a file however I want to use it on a folder... I can figure this out later

```
@ECHO ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d ') do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    copy "%%a" "C:\FolderB\!name:~0,-6!%%~xa" 
)
pause
```

I know I can rename the whole folder like `RENAME "C:\users\my profile\my word documents" "my documents"` but I want to just edit the already named folder.

---

2.

This Code adds a 0 in front of the folder name. That's all it can do so far but i would like to determine the position of adding the 0

```
@ECHO ON
for /D %%f in (*) do rename "%%f" "0%%f"
pause
```

so I  reckon making 0 into a var and then using delims and tokens to determine the position in the file name.I would be grateful for any help thanks.

I am using windows 10 64bit.

I apologize if this is a bit confusing i tried to be as brief as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to rename a folder with a date as filename to the same date, but edited. To do this you can do something along the lines of this:

```
@echo off
set "folderName=20011993"
SET newFolderName=%folderName:~0,2%_%folderName:~2,2%_%folderName:~4%
echo ren %folderName% %newFolderName%
pause
```

This assumes you have the folderName saved to a variable already. For more information on variable substrings you should look at [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Note that this echoes the command to rename, to actually rename the folder you should remove the `echo` from that line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a folder structure something like this:

```
├───20011993
│   ├───someFile.txt
│   └───anotherFile.txt
├───21011993
│   └───andAnotherFile.txt
└───22011993
    └───yetAnotherFile.txt
```

You can run this from the parent directory that holds those folders.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir ????1993 /b/ad ') do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    echo ren "!name!" "!name:~0,2!-!name:~2,2!-!name:~4,4!"
)
```

If you have folders that span several years, you can iterate through each year as a number using a `for /l` loop.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set beginYear=1993
set endYear=2016
for /l %%x in (%beginYear%,1,%endYear%) do call :renameLoop %%x

:renameLoop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir ????%1 /b/ad ') do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    echo ren "!name!" "!name:~0,2!_!name:~2,2!_!name:~4,4!"
)
```